# Update array value inside observable typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, observable

How do you write a function that takes an Observable<T[]> and updates the value inside the observable.
I tried with the below approach but i felt i am not doing the update on proper way.
I want to update the  values of the observable with the row object.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

let gridData = [
     {
      id: '1',
      firstName: 'Sophie',
      lastName: 'Beckham',
      gender: 'F',
      jobTitle: 'Senior Associate-L1',
      jobArea: 'London',
      monthlyWage: '$100000',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      firstName: 'Sophie',
      lastName: 'Beckham',
      gender: 'F',
      jobTitle: 'Senior Associate-L2',
      jobArea: 'London',
      monthlyWage: '$100000',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      firstName: 'Chloe',
      lastName: 'Bryson',
      gender: 'F',
      jobTitle: 'Senior Associate-L3',
      jobArea: 'London',
      monthlyWage: '$100000',
    },
  ];

let gridData$ = of(gridData);

let row = {
     id: '2',
      firstName: 'TAN',
      lastName: 'Ara',
      gender: 'M',
      jobTitle: 'Senior Associate',
      jobArea: 'ATL',
      monthlyWage: '$130000',
}
gridData$.subscribe((val: any) => {
   val.forEach((list: any) => {
     if(list['id'] === row['id']){
        for (const property in row) {
          list[property]  = row[property];
       }
     }
   })
})
gridData$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

In my approach i have used for loop and based on the object id updating the value. If there is a better approach, kindly share your approach.

StackBlitz :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gdgkyk?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: In this case, the first `subscribe` is just an indirect way of accessing the underlying array which you already have access to. If the observable didn't reuse the same underlying for each subscription, like if it created a new array, this would not work. Instead, try `modifiedGridData$ = gridData$.pipe(map(val => // modify and return array))`. Also, `.subscribe((val: any) => ` and `.forEach((list: any) => ` is bad code. Instead, write `.subscribe((val) => ` and `.forEach((list) => ` - keeping your types around. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-saevva?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: @AluanHaddad worked

Answer (score 3):

Observables are stateless and its recommended that emitted values are immutable.

But you can return a new observable that returns what you want by using the `map` operator (on all values).

Note that I've used `from` instead of `of` operator.

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

let gridData$ = from(gridData);

...

gridData$ = gridData$.pipe(
  map((val: any) => {
   
     if(val['id'] === row['id']){
        for (const property in row) {
          val[property]  = row[property];
       }
     }

     return val;
 })
);

gridData$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

Now each time you call `gridData$` it will execute the new observable.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6mh6iu